# How to get a Stack in a SliverToBoxAdapter to size according to its content

Tags: flutter, dart, stack

I have a CustomScrollView with a SliverToBoxAdapter to show a header, and a SliverGrid to show a list of elements.
I need to have a Stack in my header, to be able to have widgets over an image, one of those widgets is a text whose length is not fixed
and which I need to be able to expand by clicking a "Read more".
The problem I have is that the Stack widget always takes the maximum size instead of adapting its size to the size of its children.

I have made a sample app to illustrate my problem.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'my test app',
      home: StackTest(),
    );
  }
}
class Header extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LimitedBox(
     maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,

    child : Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child : Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                top : 100,
                child : Container(
                  color:Colors.blue,
                  child: Text("this is a test header"),
                )
            )
          ],
        )));
  }
}

class StackTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StackTestState  createState()  => _StackTestState();

}
class _StackTestState extends State<StackTest> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

    final List<String> list = ["a", "b", "c", "d","e"];

    return Container(
    child : CustomScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Header()),
          SliverGrid(
            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(

                crossAxisCount: 3,
                crossAxisSpacing: 2,
                mainAxisSpacing: 2,
                childAspectRatio: 1),
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(

                childCount: list.length , (context, index) {
              return Container(
                  child: Text(list[index]));
            }),
          )
        ]
    ));
  }
}
```

My first problem is that flutter forces me to put the Stack in a Widget that can limit its size, in the example above  I used a LimitedBox.
The second problem is that the Stack  takes the full heigth allowed by the LimitedBox instead of taking just enough space for the Text widget.

I tried with just the text in the header without the stack, and I also tried with a Stack that is not in a SliverToBoxAdapter, in both cases the Stack takes the expected size.
But when the Stack is in the SlivertoBoxAdapter it seems it doesn't behave the same way.

How can I do to get the Stack in the SliverToBoxAdapter to  takes only the size it needs for its children ?

Thanks